# Probability of a triangle in a circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, triangles

I'm confused on my calculations on analytic geometry with probability. Things I learned on these were messed up since I was a newbie on these subjects. Here's my problem:

Three points are chosen uniformly at random from the perimeter of circle. The probability that the triangle formed by these is acute can be expressed as $a/b$  where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers. What is the value of $a+b$?

You may provide explanations so I would know how it was solved. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate.  The fact that the triangle is acute if and only if the center of the circle is in its interior is in itself a mathematical proposition that may be worthy of attention in this context.

Comment: I'm sorry and I don't know that the question has exact contents as the previous one. But thanks for informing me about this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I think that if this is not an exact duplicate it is the closest thing to it: anyone attempting to answer the current question should be, imo, aware of basic geometry facts, so the present question and the one Adriano mentions are one and the same.

Comment: This is a problem posted on Brilliant, as is several of OP's questions. Bryan, you can view the solutions directly.